# Three "Nested loop join" in the Execution plan despite using two inner joins in the main query

Tags: oracle, query-performance, oracle-11g-r2, execution-plan, plsql

I have a query as you can see below :

```
with cte as
 (select customer_num
    from vmi_segment_customer_relation
   where effective_date = to_date('12/30/2021', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
     and segment_id = 10000000592
     )
select 
 t.customer_num, 
 cust_first_name, 
 cust_last_name, 
 cust_type_desc
  from vmi_factcustomer t
  join cte f
    on t.customer_num = f.customer_num
   and t.effective_date = to_date('12/30/2021', 'mm/dd/yyyy')

  join vmi_dimcustomer d
    on t.customer_num = d.customer_num;
```

As you can see, there are three tables in this query

1)`vmi_segment_customer_relation` , Index: `"IDX1_SEGMENT"` on `"segment_id"`  column.

2)`vmi_factcustomer` , Index: `"IDX1_F"` on `"customer_num"`  column.

3)`vmi_dimcustomer` , Index: `"IDX_CUSTNUM"` on `"customer_num"` column.

All table's `statistics` are up to date and there is no stale statistics. I got the real `execution plan` for this query using this hint `/*+gather_plan_statistics*/` as you can see here is the plan :

[image]

I have some question regarding the plan :

1. I expected the `operation-10` to be under the `operation-11` (op-10 be the child of op-11) because the `'IDX_CUSTNUM'` index is for `'MI_DIMCUSTOMER'` table ! Take a look at `op-5 and op-6` for example . Or `op-8 and op-9` , I expected to wee op-10 and op-11 exactly like the two and have no idea why it is not!
2. Another question is that , there are two joins in the query , so why we see three `Nested loop joins` in the plan? What is the role for each nested loops??

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably should post the plan as properly formatted text, [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: @mustaccio . Thanks for the comment .Just give me some time and I'm gonna do that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be assigning too much meaning to the operation ID. It is there simply to uniquely identify each operation and has nothing to do with the order of operation execution.

You need to read the plan "inside out", from the most nested operation to the less nested one. With that in mind, let's see what is happening:

- Op. 6. `IDX1_SEGMENT` is scanned to retrieve `ROWID`s matching the segment.
- Op. 5. The rows from `MI_SEGMENT_CUSTOMER_RELATION` are read by `ROWID` to filter those that match the `EFFECTIVE_DATE` condition and get `CUSTOMER_NUM`.
- Op. 3. Loop over the retrieved `CUSTOMER_NUM` values.
- Op. 9. In the loop `IDX1_F` is scanned to find entries matching `CUSTOMER_NUM` from Op. 5, and the corresponding `ROWID`s are retrieved.
- Op. 8. The rows from `MI_FACTCUSTOMER` are read by `ROWID` to filter those that match the `EFFECTIVE_DATE` condition and get `CUSTOMER_NUM`.
- Op. 2. Loop over the `CUSTOMER_NUM` values from Op. 8.
- Op. 10. In the loop access `IDX_CUSTOMER` to fetch `ROWID`s matching the customer number.
- Op. 1. Loop over `ROWID`s from Op. 10.
- Op. 11. In the loop access `MI_DIMCUSTOMER` to fetch the required columns.

Obviously, those loops are executed simultaneously: as soon as the new value from Op. 5 is available, the next iteration of Ops. 9 and 8 can proceed, and as soon as that is complete, the next iteration of Ops. 10 and 11 can fetch the required data.

Given the small number of rows and the presence of useful indexes the choice of the nested loop join seems appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation . Still have not got the answer to the second question which is why do we see 3 Nested Loops despite having 2 Inner joins in the query?  3 nested loops in the plan is a bit confusing for me

Comment: Still can not understand the role of first Nested loop! What does it do exactly ?? In the second Nested loop which is operation number 2 , all the joins between three tables are finished and the rows satisfying the condition of the joins are survived ! what does the first nested loop join do ?